# How to detect and remove empty XML tags?

Tags: xml, powershell, tags

I've got a bunch of XML files, I wish to detect and remove empty tags inside them. like:

```
<My></My>
<Your/>

<sometags>
    <his>
    </his>
    <hasContent>sdfaf</hasContent>
</sometags>
```

They're all kinds of empty tags (`My`, `Your`, `his`) I wish to remove. Does PowerShell support such kind of empty tag detection, no matter how deep they're embedded inside other tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function Format-XML
{ 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][xml] $xml, 
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][int] $indent = 4
    ) 

    try
    {
        $Error.Clear()

        $StringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter 
        $XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter $StringWriter 
        $xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented" 
        $xmlWriter.Indentation = $indent 
        $xml.WriteContentTo($XmlWriter) 
        $XmlWriter.Flush() 
        $StringWriter.Flush() 

        return $StringWriter.ToString() 
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"; return $null
    }
}


$xml = [xml] @"
<document>
    <My></My>
    <Your/>
    <sometags>
        <his>
        </his>
        <hasContent>sdfaf</hasContent>
    </sometags>
</document>
"@

# The "magic" part is in this XPath expression

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[count(@*) = 0 and count(child::*) = 0 and not(string-length(text())) > 0]")

$nodes | %{
    $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}

Format-Xml $xml
```

Comment: Thanks, but would you help to explain the 3 sub parts of the magic XPath string?

Comment: As a side note, Jeffrey Snover updated the [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/01/18/format-xml.aspx) where he posted that formatting function with an even niftier suggestion from Lee Holmes: `$xml.Save([Console]::Out)`.

Comment: Sees $xml.Save doesn't exist for [xml], I just tried:
    $xml = @"
    <document>
    <My></My>
    <Your/>
    <sometags>
        <his>
        </his>
        <hasContent>sdfaf</hasContent>
    </sometags>
    </document>
    "@
    $x=[xml]$xml
    $x.Save([Console]::Out)

    <?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>documentMyMyYour /sometagshishishasContentsdfafhasContentsometagsdocument

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fluent in powershell, so only a little addition to [@DavidBrabant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311712/david-brabant)'s good answer, specifically in the xpath part. xpath for detecting empty elements can be a bit simpler :

```
//*[not(@*) and not(*) and normalize-space()]
```

The predicates (everything within `[]`), in order, checks if current element doesn't have attribute, doesn't have child element, and doesn't have empty text node.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a solution that uses System.Xml.XmlDocument. But its also possible using regex:

```
$xml = @"
<document>
    <My></My>
    <Your/>
    <sometags>
        <his>
        </his>
        <hasContent>sdfaf</hasContent>
    </sometags>
</document>
"@

$xml -replace '(?:<(\w*)>\s*<\/\1>)|<(\w*)\/>', ''
```